# Troubleshooting DC motor

Tags: motor

I worked on the starterkit project #9 motorized pinwheel, and the motor worked just fine.

I then tried to add a potentiometer, and now the motor won't rotate at all any more (neither in the current nor in the project's baseline configuration). I also tried connecting the motor to the 9V battery directly, to no avail.

I did check the battery by briefly connecting a LED right away. The motor apparently also still generates current if I turn it manually (checked with a directly connected LED either).

What else can I do to check what's wrong with the motor? Is it possible that I somehow accidently killed it with my attempts with the potentiometer?

Comment: Have you tried a fresh battery? A good 9 V battery should blow a LED pretty fast if you tried to connect it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your motor doesn't work when connected to the 9V battery, either the battery is flat (which is likely since you were able to connect the LED without destroying it!! - they are a 2.5-3v part, not a 9v part) or the wiring to the motor is damaged. When you connect the motor directly to a 9v battery, it should turn pretty fast - may also work if you connect it to between 2 & 4 AA batteries.

9v batteries don't have that much energy in them... you would be better off with a battery pack with 6 AA batteries in it.